# Move specific array elements to the end in Swift

Tags: arrays, swift, sorting

I have an array of objects, say Contacts that look like this

```swift
class Contact {
    var name: String
    var status: Status
    
    init(name: String, status: Status) {
        self.status = status
        self.name = name
    }
}

enum Status: String {
    case referred, invalid, member
}
```

I want to sort the array of such objects so that I keep all the members at the end.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done to keep all the members at the end of the array. The original ordering is retained for other elements.

```
contacts.sort(by: { c1, c2 in
    c2.status == .member
})
```

#### Output

```
**Original array:**
Anand referred
Arti member
Abid member
Basha referred
Bumrah member
Catherine member
Cambly invalid
Faiz member
Farnades referred
Zebra member

**New Array:**
Anand referred
Basha referred
Cambly invalid
Farnades referred
Zebra member
Faiz member
Catherine member
Bumrah member
Abid member
Arti member
```

Comment: Hi @Faizyy, what is going on here, you answered your question at the same time when you made it!?

Comment: @EgzonP. FYI, Stackoverflow allows you to share your knowledge, by providing an answer to your own question at the same time. 
I did this primarily because I could not find an answer for my question and had to figure out on my own. Someone else might have the same question in the future.

Comment: Hi @Faizyy I understand all that but you made the question and answer at the same time. I think you should make questions in Stackoverflow for things you don't know. The way you are doing it's better to create blog posts in Medium for example or something, because if we all start making questions and answers for things "others might need" we would have a massive place with almost unwanted things with an answer. Again, I'm asking you this because you made the question at 09:25:35 0Z and the answer at the same time, 09:25:35 0Z. I highly do not recommend you doing such a thing! All the best!

Comment: Sorting doesn't guarantee the order of the original array will be preserved, in case two elements are considered equal. It might work for some sets of data, but it might return the elements in the two partitions in a different order than in the input array, for other sets of data.

Comment: @Cristik Please don't scare me. I have written this code and it seems to be working for most of the cases. I partially agree to your comment that the second half of the array won't be in order. But order of the first half (status != member) will be retained always.

Comment: @Faizyy the sort algorithm is here: https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/main/stdlib/public/core/Sort.swift. You can assume that it keeps the relative order, but I don't think the `sort` method makes such guarantees.

Comment: More, the header docs for the sorting functionality say that `The sorting algorithm is not guaranteed to be stable. A stable sort preserves the relative order of elements that compare equal.`. So there are no guarantees that using `sort` will behave as you need (https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/main/stdlib/public/core/Sort.swift#L40).

Comment: Thank you so much for the info. I shall reconsider my approach :|